# Interpolating data based on nearest dates in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets that I would like to interpolate based on nearest time and a conditional value.

I'd like to mix Dataset A

```
df.a <- read.table(text=
                     '"Time1","Var1","User"
                   2016-06-05 21:08:38,a,1
                   2016-06-06 10:47:34,b,1
                   2016-06-06 11:27:07,a,2
                   2016-06-06 14:49:05,b,2'
                   , header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

which is:

```
Time1               Var1    User
2016-06-05 21:08:38 a       1
2016-06-06 10:47:34 b       1
2016-06-06 11:27:07 a       2
2016-06-06 14:49:05 b       2
```

and dataset B

```
df.b <- read.table(text=
                      '"Time2", "Var2", "User"
                    2016-06-06 08:08:52,x,1
                    2016-06-06 08:40:51,x,1
                    2016-06-06 09:17:52,y,1
                    2016-06-06 09:28:23,y,1
                    2016-06-06 10:49:57,z,1
                    2016-06-06 11:07:24,z,1
                    2016-06-06 11:58:49,x,2
                    2016-06-06 12:03:14,y,2
                    2016-06-06 14:53:09,z,2
                    2016-06-06 15:12:05,z,2'
                    , header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

which is:

```
Time2               Var2    User
2016-06-06 08:08:52 x       1
2016-06-06 08:40:51 x       1
2016-06-06 09:17:52 y       1
2016-06-06 09:28:23 y       1
2016-06-06 10:49:57 z       1
2016-06-06 11:07:24 z       1
2016-06-06 11:58:49 x       2
2016-06-06 12:03:14 y       2
2016-06-06 14:53:09 z       2
2016-06-06 15:12:05 z       2
```

So that I get dataset B back, with the closest matching date from dataset A, where `a$User` == `b$User`.

```
Time2               Var2    User    Time1               Var1
2016-06-06 08:08:52 x       1       2016-06-05 21:08:38 a
2016-06-06 08:40:51 x       1       2016-06-05 21:08:38 a
2016-06-06 09:17:52 y       1       2016-06-05 21:08:38 a
2016-06-06 09:28:23 y       1       2016-06-05 21:08:38 a
2016-06-06 10:49:57 z       1       2016-06-06 10:47:34 b
2016-06-06 11:07:24 z       1       2016-06-06 10:47:34 b
2016-06-06 11:58:49 x       2       2016-06-06 11:27:07 a
2016-06-06 12:03:14 y       2       2016-06-06 11:27:07 a
2016-06-06 14:53:09 z       2       2016-06-06 14:49:05 b
2016-06-06 15:12:05 z       2       2016-06-06 14:49:05 b
```

Which requires a conditional matching: minimum time difference, where `a$user` == `b$user`

The closest I can get is a cross join, but that doesn't scale for my original data sets where A = 3 million records, and B = 20 million records

Comment: Is dataset B bigger than A? And does dataset A only contain 2 unique values for `Var1`?

Comment: @akash87 I clarified the question. Yes, B is always bigger than A, the result set should be of size B

Comment: And does Dataset A only contain 2 unique values for `Var1`?

Comment: @akash87 nope, could be up to 20 values

Answer (score 0):

To begin, first convert all your date and time data into the appropriate format.

```
df.a$Time1 <- as.POSIXct(df.a$Time1)
df.b$Time2 <- as.POSIXct(df.b$Time2)
```

Now go from long data in `df.a` to wide data using and merge to `df.b`. We choose `df.a` to `reshape` from long to wide data because it is the smaller dataset.

```
df.a.w <- reshape(df.a, idvar = 'User', timevar = 'Var1', direction = 'wide')
df     <- merge(df.b, df.a.w, by = 'User', all.x = T)
```

Now with the data merged, you can proceed to use `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages in R. They are used quite a bit together to manage and wrangle data.

```
df.l   <- data.frame(df %>% gather(TimeType, Time1,-User, -Var2, -Time2) %>% 
                     separate(TimeType, into = c('TimeL', "Var1"), sep = "\\.") %>%
                     select(-TimeL)   %>%
                     filter(Time2 > Time1)            %>%
                     group_by(User, Time2, Var2)      %>%
                     slice(which.min(Time2-Time1)))
```

Here we get the data as you requested, in a data.frame format. There may be a better solution using `data.table` but I am not that good with that package.